# Paypal not working for the logged in customer console error showing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'done') "

Tags: magento2, magento-community, magento2.3.4

I am facing a strange issue, when a logged customer wants to place an order with Paypal then it is showing an error in the console but with guest checkout, it is working perfectly.

I have checked the file "vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-rendererpaypal-express-abstract.js" and found below code.

```
/** Redirect to paypal */
    continueToPayPal: function () {
        if (additionalValidators.validate()) {
            //update payment method information if additional data was changed
            this.selectPaymentMethod();
            setPaymentMethodAction(this.messageContainer).done(
                function () {
                    customerData.invalidate(['cart']);
                    $.mage.redirect(
                        window.checkoutConfig.payment.paypalExpress.redirectUrl[quote.paymentMethod().method]
                    );
                }
            );
            

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please help me ?

If I comment "setPaymentMethodAction(this.messageContainer).done()" function then will it work and will not create any other issue ?

Magento version :- 2.3.4

[image]

Comment: I'm making the same mistake, were you able to fix it?
did you by chance change your paypal email or in the sales section?
@Parbat Singh

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this.
Remove this.select Payment Method(); it was removed in later versions.
I fixed this by editing set-payment-information-extended.js , I was using a onestepcheckout module which gave me this problem.